# jQuery Mobile: automatically adding scrollbar if options list is too long

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have multiple select menus on my jQuery Mobile website. I was wondering how I can achieve that a scrollbar is shown in the options list if the number of option element is larger than 5?

My JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/asvyY/51/

My code:

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header">
         <h1>My page</h1> 
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <form>
            <select class="filter-menu" data-native-menu="false">
               <option value="1">1</option>
               <option value="2">2</option>
               <option value="3">3</option>
               <option value="4">4</option>
               <option value="5">5</option>
            </select>

            <select class="filter-menu" data-native-menu="false">
               <option value="1">1</option>
               <option value="2">2</option>
               <option value="3">3</option>
               <option value="4">4</option>
               <option value="5">5</option>
               <option value="6">6</option>
               <option value="7">7</option>
               <option value="8">8</option>
               <option value="9">9</option>
               <option value="10">10</option>
            </select>

            <select class="filter-menu" data-native-menu="false">
               <option value="1">1</option>
               <option value="2">2</option>
               <option value="3">3</option>
               <option value="4">4</option>
               <option value="5">5</option>
               <option value="6">6</option>
               <option value="7">7</option>
               <option value="8">8</option>
               <option value="9">9</option>
               <option value="10">10</option>
               <option value="11">11</option>
               <option value="12">12</option>
               <option value="13">13</option>
               <option value="14">14</option>
               <option value="15">15</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$.mobile.document
    .on("listviewcreate", function (e) {

        var input,
        listbox = $(".filter-menu-listbox"),
            form = listbox.jqmData("filter-form"),
            listview = $(e.target);

        if (!form) {
            listbox = $("<ul class='.filter-menu-listbox'></ul>");
            input = $("<input data-type='search'></input>");
            form = $("<form></form>").append(input);

            input.textinput();

            listbox
                .prepend(form)
                .jqmData("filter-form", form);

            listview.prepend(listbox);
        }

        listview.filterable({
            input: input
        });
    })
```

Comment: Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/asvyY/52/)? Add `max-height: 270px; overflow-y: auto;` to `.ui-selectmenu.ui-dialog .ui-selectmenu-list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.ui-selectmenu.ui-dialog .ui-selectmenu-list {
    margin-top: 0;
    height: 270px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: Did you steal this from my comment?